# SMO : Get Server Permission Set for a login (ServerPermissionSet)

Tags: sql-server, powershell, smo

Trying to get a ServerPermissionSet for a login and apply it to a new login. Can't seem to grasp if there is a relationship between the ServerPermissionSet and a Server.Login, or if there is a better way to do this. I can do this with tSQL, but am trying to look at this from the SMO perspective. Here is some sudo code on what I am trying to accomplish.

```
$server = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') 
"my_server"
$sps = new-object -TypeName 
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.ServerPermissionSet
$newlogin = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Login') $Server, 
"new_login"
$oldlogin = $server.Logins["old_login"]
// THIS PART OBVIOUSLY DOESN'T WORK
$newlogin.Create("password")
$sps = $oldlogin.ServerPermissionSet
$server.Grant($sps,"new_login")
```

Comment: Why not tsql? Can you run whatever tsql code to do your logic and use `Invoke-Sqlcmd` to get the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using the code example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/tasks/granting-revoking-and-denying-permissions) to inform my answer:

```
$server = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') 
"my_server"
$newlogin = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Login') $Server, 
"new_login"

$newlogin.Create("password")
$sps = $server.EnumServerPermissions("old_login")
$server.Grant($sps,"new_login")
```

That is, you have to ask the server to enumerate the server permissions for old_login which will generate a ServerPermissionSet[] which you can then pass to the Grant method on the server object.

But I do have to ask: is there a reason not to use a server-level role to encapsulate these permissions and just grant membership in the role to the new login?

Comment: Thanks for the response. This enough to send me down the right path. Server Roles could accomplish this, but there are users who have rights already granted to them and I need to identify those rights. Also I am trying to create a process that will transfer users to another server which might not have the same Server Role configured.